# When turn off EF Core ChangeTracker

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I use .Net for the back-end. Since evaluation and modification done in the application layer and this layer is unaware of EF Core ORM, is it useful to have change tracker in this senario?

The API layer would get the data from application layer and return it to the (react) client. the changed data comes from the API method to the application layer. Then the injected repository is being called to persist the modified data.

My question is what is the best practice to use change tracker? (when we do not use .Net stack for the client or UI layer)

Comment: None of your "get" methods need change tracking, you can easily turn those off. The updates (inserts, updates, deletes) are more tricky. There are ways to avoid loading the entity first, but one way or another change tracker needs to know something has been modified for it to help generate the proper modification queries.

Comment: For the inserts, updates, and deletes, I do not want to expose EF change tracker concept to the application layer and count on it. Is this the best practice? Am I right? @TanveerBadar

Comment: It can be done, your application need not be aware of how the data persistence is implemented.